# GUI volume indicator in Openbox

Tags: gui, desktop-environment, desktop, openbox, audio-volume

I am using plain openbox as my window manager.

I have configured keyboard special keys, such as `XF86AudioMute`, `XF86AudioLowerVolume` and `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`.

But how can I get the gui indicator, when I am changing audio levels?
What I mean is, I would like to see the "percentage bar" where my volme currently is, when I am changing it

is this a function that can be configured in openbox? Or do I need some external utility?
How do other desktp environmets do this ?

and I am using `fbpanel` as my desktop panel, in case it is relevant.